# Writing to s3: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am getting the following error from the very last line of my script in AWS Lambda when trying to write a cav file to a bucket:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "expected string or bytes-like object, got 's3.Bucket'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "14b29de4-bf60-4125-b59e-e9fb6e3032ed",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 190, in lambda_handler\n    s3_dx.Object(dx_bucket, prefix + 'items.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py\", line 580, in do_action\n    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py\", line 88, in __call__\n    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 535, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 928, in _make_api_call\n    api_params = self._emit_api_params(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 1043, in _emit_api_params\n    self.meta.events.emit(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\", line 412, in emit\n    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\", line 256, in emit\n    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\", line 239, in _emit\n    response = handler(**kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py\", line 278, in validate_bucket_name\n    if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 14b29de4-bf60-4125-b59e-e9fb6e3032ed Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 's3.Bucket'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 190, in lambda_handler
    s3_dx.Object(dx_bucket, prefix + 'items.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 580, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 88, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 535, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 928, in _make_api_call
    api_params = self._emit_api_params(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1043, in _emit_api_params
    self.meta.events.emit(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 278, in validate_bucket_name
    if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):END RequestId: 14b29de4-bf60-4125-b59e-e9fb6e3032ed
REPORT RequestId: 14b29de4-bf60-4125-b59e-e9fb6e3032ed  Duration: 8542.55 ms    Billed Duration: 8543 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB Init Duration: 3194.20 ms
```

here is my code:

```
csv_buffer = StringIO()
new_df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
prefix="0001/dates/"
s3_dx = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=day, aws_secret_access_key= ask)   
s3_dx.Object('bucket', prefix + 'names.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Any thoughts on whats causing the error?

Comment: It doesn't look like that code could cause that exception. Which line of code causes the error (include the stack trace)?

Comment: The very last line, which is also the last line of the script. Edited the post to include the stack

Comment: You appear to be passing `dx_bucket`, which is presumably an [s3.Bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/index.html) object, into the S3 Object constructor, when the API expects a string representing the bucket name. Alternatively, you can use `dx_bucket.Object(key)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception shown doesn't match the code you've included, but the problem is that you are passing `dx_bucket`, which is presumably an instance of [s3.Bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/index.html), into the S3 Object constructor, when the API expects a string representing the bucket name.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. pass the bucket name as a string when calling s3.Object()
2. use the bucket's [Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/Object.html) sub-resource

```py
import boto3
    
BUCKET = "mybucket"
    
csv = "james,mary,william"
prefix="0001/dates/"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    
# Option 1: create an Object directly
s3.Object(BUCKET, prefix + 'names.csv').put(Body=csv)
    
# Option 2: use the Bucket to create the Object
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)
bucket.Object(prefix + 'names.csv').put(Body=csv)
```